# read integer through a socket c

Tags: c, int

i need to read an integer through a socket and the sens it to a function. i do

```
strcpy(out,"insert id messagge\n");
if (write(sd_client,out, sizeof(out))==-1){
    printf("Error.\n");
    }
while ((read(sd_client, &id, sizeof(int)))==-1){  //id is an integer
        if(errno!=EINTR){
    printf("Error.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
}
messaggio2(sd_client, logi, atoi(id)); //atoi(id) try to send int to func
```

someone can help me please? :D

Comment: How are you sending the integer ?

Comment: If sd_client is a TCP socket, then you can't be guaranteed that "read" will return all the bytes you ask for.  See this answer I gave before.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125286/one-problem-with-read-function-in-c/5125366

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of `read` and `write` is a *pointer* to the data.

When you say:

```
write(sd_client,out, sizeof(out))
```

you're passing the *value* of out. That should be:

```
write(sd_client, &out, sizeof(out))
```

Also, I think that you've declared `id` as int (which is correct), so why are you passing it to `atoi`? That function is for parsing a int from a string.

Comment: i use atoi, but it doesn't work, that's why i'm asking for help. i try different way, that is just the least one. In final i need to read an integer through a socket and than see if it's the same of another int

Comment: `write(sd_client, out, sizeof(out))` is writing all of `out`. `read(sd_client, &id, sizeof(int))` is reading bytes into `id` to form an int. As I said, `atoi` takes a _string_ and returns an int, for example, `atoi("123")` returns `123`. You're trying to pass it an int.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having seems a bit vague since you haven't actually mentioned the errors you're getting, but from the code you have posted, it seems like you are running into two different problems:

1. `atoi()` is for converting a string value to an integer ... now it seems you already have an integer in the value of `id`, so the argument to `atoi()` is incorrect.  You would simply need to use something like `sprintf()` or `snprintf()` to convert your integer value to a string value and then copy that into a user-defined string-buffer if you are wanting a string-representation of your integer.
2. You are working with sockets, therefore any information transferred over the network will be coming in network-byte-order.  If you are on a little-endian platform, then the integer will be coming in a big-endian format, and you will be interpreting the value of your integer incorrect.  Therefore you should be converting your integer to the native platform endian format using a function like `ntohl()` which can be found inside of the header file `netinet/in.h`

So for instance:

```
#include <netinet/in.h>

int id;
int sd_client;

//... code to open socket, etc.

//add your own error-checking ... stripped out here for simplicity's sake
read(sd_client, &id, sizeof(int));
id = ntohl(id);

char buffer[32];
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d", id);
messaggio2(sd_client, logi, buffer);
```

Comment: i don't want a string, i need an integer. making the read whit &id doesn't  work. now whit this code

Comment: while ((read(sd_client, &id, sizeof(int)))==-1){
    if(errno!=EINTR){
     printf("Errore in lettura.\n");
     exit(-1);
    }
   }
   printf("%d\n",id);
   id = ntohl(id);
   printf("%d\n",id);

Comment: if the client write 4 the first print is 52.
after the ntohl i make the same print and value is 8572415232.
I need that id value is 4 after the read in this case, not 52 or the other

Comment: On the client side you need to also call 'htonl()' before sending the 'int' value of '4'

Comment: Finally, 8572415232 is larger than a 32-bit value ... are you sure that's the value you're getting?